# how to display php variable , name by id in html tooltip title=""

Tags: php, html

how i can display the language by country name and not by country code in my tooltip `title=""`
i have try multiple possibility but nothing work

```
$alllangues = Array("" => "Englich", "fr" => "French", "es" => "Spanich", "it" => "Italian", "pt" => "Portuguese");

 <?php foreach ($alllangues as $rKey => $rLanguage) { if ($rUser["lang"] == $rKey) { ?>

<span data-bs-toggle="tooltip"  data-bs-placement="left" title="<?=$rKey?>"><?=$rLanguage?></span>

<?php } } ?>
```

so my code is correct its only this part , i dont know how to enter `$rLanguage` in  `title=""`

thank you for your answer

i think im tired , thanks for your help
its work like this

```
 <?php echo "<span data-bs-toggle='tooltip'  data-bs-placement='left' title='{$alllangues[$rUser["lang"]]}'>";?>
```

but if i close the span the tooltip not work i dont know why like this not work :

```
 <?php echo "<span data-bs-toggle='tooltip'  data-bs-placement='left' title='{$alllangues[$rUser["lang"]]}'></form>";?>
```

this work better without echo

```
<span data-bs-toggle="tooltip"  data-bs-placement="left" title="<?=$alllangues[$rUser["lang"]]?>">
```

so thank you guys have a good day, and respect

Comment: Why not use `echo $rLanguage`?

Comment: cause need to select lang by user connected $rUser["lang"]

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the while loop to print the language
try something like this

```
echo "<span data-bs-toggle='tooltip'  data-bs-placement='left' title='{$rUser["lang"]}'>{$alllangues[$rUser["lang"]]}</span>";
```

I hope it's useful

Comment: @NicoHaase https://3v4l.org/pEuSQ

Comment: thank you sir for your answer , so with you code its same result the {$alllangues[$rUser["lang"]]}  is outside the title="" i need it inside